# Unable to build a docker image following Docker Tutorial

Tags: python, docker

I was following this [tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/02_our_app/) on a Macbook to build a sample Docker image but when I tried to run the following command:

```
docker build -t getting-started .
```

I got the following error:

```
[+] Building 3.2s (15/24)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 1.05kB                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => => transferring context: 34B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/nginx:alpine                                                                                                                                                                                                             2.7s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:alpine                                                                                                                                                                                                            2.7s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:12-alpine                                                                                                                                                                                                           2.7s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => => transferring context: 7.76kB                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => [base 1/4] FROM docker.io/library/python:alpine@sha256:94cfb962c71da780c5f3d34c6e9d1e01702b8be1edd2d450c24aead4774aeefc                                                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => => resolve docker.io/library/python:alpine@sha256:94cfb962c71da780c5f3d34c6e9d1e01702b8be1edd2d450c24aead4774aeefc                                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => CACHED [stage-5 1/3] FROM docker.io/library/nginx:alpine@sha256:686aac2769fd6e7bab67663fd38750c135b72d993d0bb0a942ab02ef647fc9c3                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => CACHED [app-base 1/8] FROM docker.io/library/node:12-alpine@sha256:1ea5900145028957ec0e7b7e590ac677797fa8962ccec4e73188092f7bc14da5                                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => CANCELED [app-base 2/8] RUN apk add --no-cache python g++ make                                                                                                                                                                                                          0.5s
 => CACHED [base 2/4] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => CACHED [base 3/4] COPY requirements.txt .                                                                                                                                                                                                                               0.0s
 => CACHED [base 4/4] RUN pip install -r requirements.txt                                                                                                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => CACHED [build 1/2] COPY . .                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             0.0s
 => ERROR [build 2/2] RUN mkdocs build                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      0.4s
------                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
 > [build 2/2] RUN mkdocs build:
#23 0.378 Traceback (most recent call last):
#23 0.378   File "/usr/local/bin/mkdocs", line 5, in <module>
#23 0.378     from mkdocs.__main__ import cli
#23 0.378   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mkdocs/__main__.py", line 14, in <module>
#23 0.378     from mkdocs import config
#23 0.378   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mkdocs/config/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
#23 0.378     from mkdocs.config.defaults import DEFAULT_SCHEMA
#23 0.378   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mkdocs/config/defaults.py", line 4, in <module>
#23 0.378     from mkdocs.config import config_options
#23 0.378   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mkdocs/config/config_options.py", line 5, in <module>
#23 0.378     from collections import Sequence, namedtuple
#23 0.378 ImportError: cannot import name 'Sequence' from 'collections' (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/collections/__init__.py)
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c mkdocs build]: exit code: 1
```

The Dockerfile I used:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM node:12-alpine
RUN apk add --no-cache python g++ make
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN yarn install --production
CMD ["node", "src/index.js"]
```

The sample app is from: https://github.com/docker/getting-started/tree/master/app

I'm pretty new to Docker and would appreciate if someone could help point out how I can get this working.

**Solutions:**

It turns out there were two issues here:

1. I should have run the `docker build -t getting-started .` command from the `/app` folder where my newly-created Dockerfile is located. In my test, I ran the command from the root folder where there was a different Dockerfile as @HansKilian pointed out. Once I tried it inside the `/app` folder, it worked fine.
2. The problem with the Docker file in the root folder is caused by a Python version mismatch issue, as pointed out by @atline in the answer. Once I made the change as suggested, I could also build an image using that Dockerfile.

Thank you both for your help.

Comment: The build log you show looks like it's from a python app (`FROM python:alpine`, `RUN pip install -r requirements.txt` etc.), but the Dockerfile you show and the Github repo you link is a Node app.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See its [Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker/getting-started/blob/master/Dockerfile#L3), it uses `FROM python:alpine AS base`, which means it used a shared tag. Another word, at the time the document wrote, `python:alpine` means maybe `python:3.9-alpine` or others.

But now, it means `python:3.10-alpine`, see [this](https://hub.docker.com/_/python).

The problems happens at `mkdocs` itself, it uses next code:

```
from collections import Sequence, namedtuple
```

But, if you have a import for above in a python3.9 environment, you will see next, which tell you it will stop working from python3.10:

```
$ docker run --rm -it python:3.9-alpine /bin/sh
/ # python
Python 3.9.7 (default, Aug 31 2021, 19:01:35)
[GCC 10.3.1 20210424] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from collections import Sequence
<stdin>:1: DeprecationWarning: Using or importing the ABCs from 'collections' instead of from 'collections.abc' is deprecated since Python 3.3, and in 3.10 it will stop working
```

So, for you, to make the guide works again for you, you need to change `FROM python:alpine AS base` to:

`FROM python:3.9-alpine AS base`

Comment: Or increase `mkdoc` to `1.2.2` also works.

Comment: Thanks @atline for your help. I updated the Dockerfile as you suggested and it worked fine now. Re your comments about upgrading mkdoc, should i upgrade the package on my Mac or specify it in the Dockerfile?

Comment: Update it in requirements.txt I think.

Comment: I had the same issue. Getting it to build was as simple as opening requirements.txt and changing `mkdoc` to `1.2.2` as atline suggested.

Answer (score 3):

I checked latest mkdocs and latest build 1.3.0 but look like it has a lot of change for change branch version from 1.2 -> 1.3 so I get the latest 1.2.4.

My requirements.txt from "mkdocs==1.2.2" to "mkdocs==1.2.4".
and i dont touch Dockerfile.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This answer appears not to be related to OP's question.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31387204)

Answer (score 1):

There is currently a known `mkdocs` issue.

https://forums.docker.com/t/jinja-mkdocs-issue-breaks-docker101tutorial/122671

Temporary fix for `docker101tutorial`

```
# requirements.txt
jinja2==3.0.3
```

Answer (score 1):

I edited requirements.txt from mkdocs 1.2.3 to mkdocs 1.2.4, and now it is working.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).